# wordpress custom css class

Tags: css, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am attempting to modify the width of the ninja form text inputs on my wordpress site. I am able to call each individually by id with:

```
#ninja_forms_field_6 {width:25%; min-width:250px;}
```

However, I would like to do so by class. However, I can't seem to figure out the correct class to call. I have looked at the source code and it displays:

```
<input id="ninja_forms_field_6" data-mask="" data-input-limit="" data-input-limit-type="char" data-input-limit-msg="character(s) left" name="ninja_forms_field_6" type="text" placeholder="First Last" class="ninja-forms-field  ninja-forms-req " value="" rel="6"   />
    <div id="ninja_forms_field_6_error" style="display:none;" class="ninja-forms-field-error">
    </div>
```

When I've tried to use:

```
.ninja-field ninja-forms-req {width:25%; min-width:250px;}
```

Nothing seems to happen. In particular, my css editor doesn't seem to like the space between ninja-field and ninja-forms-req. I've found some other answers that indidcate these are two separate tags, but I still can't seem to get the text inputs to respond to my inputs. I should note that I am using the "Simple Custom CSS" plug-in to make changes to CSS. Any help in advance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `ninja-forms-req` an element or a class?

Comment: It is class. It appears to be two classes separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.ninja-field.ninja-forms-req`.

When targetting multiple CSS classes on the same element you need to separate them with periods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried: .ninja-forms-field.ninja-forms-req  {width:25%; min-width:250px} but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try throwing an `!important` on the rule?

Comment: Assuming .ninja-forms-field.ninja-forms-req {width:25%; min-width:250px!important;} is the right syntax, it also did not work

Comment: However, .ninja-forms-field.ninja-forms-req {width:25%!important; min-width:250px!important;} did do the trick. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work really well with ninja forms and their issue with the width of buttons in some themes.  This also solved my problem using the custom css plugin.  Just use the height according to your theme button height.

```
.ninja-forms-field {
  width:100%!important;
  height:50px!important;
}
```